# validation of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, radio-button

here is my code..
    
    
     Tenders 
    
    
    Organisation Registration 
    
    
     
     *Marked Feilds are Mandatory 
    
    
     Login Name 
     
    
     
    
    
    
    
     Contact Person* 
     
    
     
    
    
    
     Firm Name* 
     
    
     
    
    
    
     Postal Address* 
     
    
     
    
    
    
    
     Country 
     
    INDIA
    
    
    
     City* 
     
    
     
    
    
    
    
     Mobile No* 
     
    
     
    
    
    
    
     Phone No. 
     
    
     
    
    
    
    
     EmailID* 
     
    
     
    
    
    
    
     Previous Projects* 
     
    
                
    
    
    
    
     Establishing Year* 
     
    
                
    
    
    
    
     Type*

```
<tr>
<td> TERMS & CONDITIONS</td>
<td> 
1. Tenderer certifies that to the best of his knowledge the particulars furnished as above by him are true, correct, complete and current in every respect. If any stage it is found that information furnished by Tenderer is untrue, inaccurate, incomplete or not-current, Railway reserves its right to reject Tenderer?s offer or terminate his contract beside taking any other legal course of action as deemed fit. 2. Permitting downloading of tender document by Railway is an added facility for convenience of Tenderer/s. Railway, however, reserves right to extend this facility for selected works or continue only with direct sale of tender forms. In case, tender document is not uploaded on website or download failure or incomplete document downloaded, Railway shall not be responsible in anyway. Railway shall not be responsible for any direct/indirect loss of business/profit resulting from inability to use this facility.<br>
3. Tenderer intends to download and print the tender document solely for the purpose of bidding for above work and downloaded document shall not be used, copied or reproduced for any other purpose.
```

4. The Tenderer agrees to pay non-refundable cost of tender document in the form prescribed in tender notice while submitting his offer. In case he fails to furnish the requisite cost of tender document in prescribed form, his offer shall be rejected. 6. The Tenderer shall keep himself updated about any modification in tender notice and tender document issued by Railway through newspapers, website or E-mail or any other means and shall act accordingly. Tenderers? offer shall be rejected if he has have not enclosed all the corrections/corrigendum along with downloaded tender documents.

```
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>  </td>
<td> 
<form name="terms" action="#" method="post">
<input type= "radio" name = "term"> Agree
<input type = "radio" name = "term"> Disagree
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>  </td>
<td> 
<form>
<input type = "submit" value = "Save" onClick=" return save_form()"> 
<input type = "reset" name = "reset" onClick="reset_form()"> 
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type= "text/javaScript">
 function save_form()
         { 
        var a= document.getElementById("text1").value;
        var b= document.getElementById("text2").value;
        var c= document.getElementById("text3").value;
        var d= document.getElementById("text4").value;
        var e= document.getElementById("text5").value;
        var f= document.getElementById("text6").value;
        var g= document.getElementById("text7").value;
        var h= document.getElementById("text8").value;
        var i= document.getElementById("text9").value;
        var j= document.getElementById("text10").value;
        var atpos= g.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos= g.lastIndexOf(".");


if (((document.form.term[0].checked==false) && (terms.term[1].checked==true)) || ((terms.term[0].checked==false) && (terms.term[1].checked==false)))
{
alert(" Agree with our agreement for your submission");
return (false);
}

else
    {
alert("You are registered");
return(true);
}
  }
```

but validation on radio buttons is not working.. please suggest the possible solution

Comment: Can you please format this so it is readable?  and possibly reduce it to a small subset of your code to display the exact problem you're having, rather than us having to read through your entire code?

Comment: i m having problem in validation of the radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean expressions don't work that way. You cannot do:

```
if((a || b || c ... || j) == null)
```

That `OR`'s all the values and compares them to `null`, which is not what you want. What you want to do is:

```
if((a == null) || (b == null) ... (j == null)) {
   ...
}
```

The same goes for your checks on `a.length`. You cannot simply `OR` all the `.length` values together and then check to see if it is less than or equal to one.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is put them all in a  control, then loop through that Divs children(which would be the fields that you want to check) and check all their values programmatically, rather than hard code each field into an `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

validating radio buttons is easy using jQuery:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="term" id="agree" value="agree"> Agree
    <input type="radio" name="term" id="disagree" value="disagree"> Disagree
<form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js">
    var termChoice;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input:radio[name="term"].change(function() {
            termChoice = $(this).is(':checked').val();
        });    
    });

    //have fun with the termChoice variable
</script>
```

//In pure js, this could e.g. be inside a validation function being called

```
if (document.getElementById('agree').checked) {
    //do stuff
}
else if (document.getElementById('disagree').checked) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: please simply the code and tell it regarding javascript without using jquery. I am making project oh html and Java.

Comment: so it's homework? Because if it isn't, this will do just fine.